# How to remove configuration files of Virtual Box from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox

I installed virtual box in ubuntu 16.04 desktop and wanted to run TrueOS in it. I must have made some mistake  while installing  TrueOS in the virtual box and it did not run.

So I uninstalled/ removed Virtual box and installed it again but it again showed TrueOS as being installed instead of a fresh install.

Upon searching, I came to know that VB keeps some configuration files etc in the HOME directory and they have to be removed. However, on opening the home directory to show hidden files also, I could not find any such file or folder.

Could someone enlighten me about the method to remove these files so that a totally fresh install can be made.
The hidden files in my home folder are :
.adobe
.cache
.compiz
.config
.gconf
.gimp2.8
.gnupg
.local
.macromedia
.mozilla
.pki
.thumbnails
.thunderbird

I am the only user and automatically the administrator.

Comment: The virtual machines are stored in `~/VirtualBox VMs`. don't you have that directory?

Comment: @JacobVlijm : But only when you did not configure them to be stored in a different place - example : my virtual disks are stored in /media/cl/virtual/vdisk to make them available from other virtualization tools like virt-manager as well ... and also because I store all personal stuff on separate partitions ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox absolutely, but I think it is safe to assume OP did not set a custom dir for the VM's :). (I store them all on a separate partition).

Comment: I do not open the hidden files or folders; I only know that they can be accessed.  All my configurations are default configurations.

Answer (score 1):

`VirtualBox` saves virtual machines in `VirtualBox VMs` directory inside your home directory. Check `~/VirtualBox VMs` and `/root/VirtualBox VMs` to find virtual machine configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to remove previous VM's is:

- start `Virtualbox`
- select the settings profile for TrueOS
- click the `Discard` icon
- go to the `File` menu and choose `Virtual Media Manager`
- select the `TrueOS.vdi` file to be removed
- click the `Remove` icon
- approve deleting all of the files associated with that VM

Comment: Thanks. Will try it.  I vote your answer as helpful, but could not find any button etc to record it.

Comment: Just click the UP arrow that appears over the number ZERO. If you also see a gray checkmark, you can click on it also, and it'll turn green, meaning you accept my answer.